# Conditional Zebra Tables

Tags: lyx, conditionals

First, I'm using LyX with a rather long preamble because I want things fairly specific, but almost all the code in the preamble is cut-n-pasted from the 'Net with a couple modifications.  I'm not a TeX guru, but I need one!

I have Zebra tables throughout almost always in a Float Table environment.  I also have a few Float Figure environments and I want the zebra effect to be off for these since its not really a table.  Its hard to explain and it looks like I can't attach an example.

What I want is a conditional (ERT is fine, but if I can fit it in the preamble, even better), that turns off Zebra tables when its in a Float: Figure environment.

Here is what I use for Zebra tables (and other table formatting) ...

```
%
% Zebra Tables w/footnotes
%
\let\mytoprule\toprule
\renewcommand{\toprule}{\mytoprule[2pt]}
\let\mybottomrule\bottomrule
\renewcommand{\bottomrule}{\mybottomrule[2pt]}
\let\mymidrule\midrule
\renewcommand{\midrule}{\mymidrule[1pt]}
\let\tabulary\tabular
\let\endtabulary\endtabular
\renewenvironment{tabular}{\rowcolors{2}{white}{shadecolor}\tabulary}   {\endtabulary}
\usepackage{footnote}
\makesavenoteenv{tabular}
```

So how do I turn all that off when \tabular is in a Float: Figure environment?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand well what you're asking, you can do that with the `etoolbox` package:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pf]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[table, x11names]{xcolor}
\usepackage{booktabs, caption}
\colorlet{shadecolor}{LightSteelBlue1}
\let\mytoprule\toprule
\renewcommand{\toprule}{\mytoprule[2pt]}
\let\mybottomrule\bottomrule
\renewcommand{\bottomrule}{\mybottomrule[2pt]}
\let\mymidrule\midrule
\renewcommand{\midrule}{\mymidrule[1pt]}
\let\tabulary\tabular
\let\endtabulary\endtabular
\renewenvironment{tabular}{\ifbool{intableenv}{\rowcolors{2}{white}{shadecolor}}{}\tabulary} {\endtabulary}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\newbool{intableenv}
\AtBeginEnvironment{table}{\booltrue{intableenv}}%{}{}
\AtEndEnvironment{table}{\boolfalse{intableenv}}{}{}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!h]
\centering
\caption{A Zebra Table}
\begin{tabular}{llccc}
\toprule
\multicolumn{2}{c} {}& \textbf{Head 1} & \textbf{Head 2} & \textbf{Head 3} \\
\midrule
 A & & & & \\
 B & & & & \\
 C & & & & \\
 D & & & & \\
 E & & & & \\
 F & & & & \\
 G & & & & \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}%
\end{table}

\begin{figure}[!h]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{llccc}
\toprule
\multicolumn{2}{c}{} & \textbf{Head 1} & \textbf{Head 2} & \textbf{Head 3} \\
\midrule
 A  & & & & \\
 B  & & & & \\
 C  & & & & \\
 D  & & & & \\
 E  & & & & \\
 F  & & & & \\
 G & & & & \\ 
 \bottomrule
\end{tabular}%
\caption{Same table}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That definately fixed it.  Worked perfectly.  Thanks

Comment: @EvanLanglois consider accepting the answer as the solution by clicking on the green checkmark.